# Get Specific Number of UserProfiles or Query on UserProfileManager to find specific user by custom property

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile, sharepoint-search, userprofilemanager

I have **total 1,00,000** users in my SharePoint but I want to get specific user by its **custom property** called **SP-EmployeeID**. I tried **KeywordQuery** of SharePoint Search with having scope as People by *below code* but it is not working as I need to find a user by Custom Property & I found that **KeywordQuery** don't work with custom property.

```
DataTable dt = GetPeople(site, "SP-EmployeeID:\"C001*\"");

private static DataTable GetPeople(SPSite spSite, string queryText)
{
    var keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(spSite)
    {
        QueryText = queryText,
        KeywordInclusion = KeywordInclusion.AllKeywords,
        HiddenConstraints = "scope:" + "\"People\"",
        SourceId = new Guid("B09A7990-05EA-4AF9-81EF-EDFAB16C4E31")
    };
    keywordQuery.RowLimit = 7;
    keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("AccountName");
    keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("SP-EmployeeID");
    SearchExecutor e = new SearchExecutor();
    ResultTableCollection rt = e.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);
    var tab = rt.Filter("TableType", KnownTableTypes.RelevantResults);
    var result = tab.FirstOrDefault();
    DataTable DT = result.Table;
    return DT;
}
```

After **unsuccessful try of SharePoint Search**, I used `GetEnumerator(100,1100)` method to iterate specific number of users (1000 users) at one time but it is not working at all.

```
SPServiceContext serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
UserProfileManager upMananger = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext);

IEnumerator profileEnumerator = upMananger.GetEnumerator(100,1100);

int i = 0;
while (profileEnumerator.MoveNext())
{
  UserProfile userProfile = profileEnumerator.Current as UserProfile;
  Console.WriteLine(userProfile.AccountName);
  i++;
}
```

Can please anyone suggest me that how can I query specific user by it's custom property? or how can I iterate only 1000 `userprofiles` at one time?

Comment: map the property `SP-EmployeeID` to a `RefinableStringXX` and then use refinement filters. Ensure that the crawl is  started and completed and then values filled up in the `RefinableStringXX` managed property

Answer (score 0):

You need to map the custom user profile property to a managed property.

I usually map to the OOTB `RefinableStringXX` properties.

Once done, do a crawl of your people content source. It will populate this managed property which you can then use as RefinementFilter in your code as below:

```
var keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(spSite)
{
    QueryText = "*",
    KeywordInclusion = KeywordInclusion.AllKeywords,
    HiddenConstraints = "scope:" + "\"People\"",
    SourceId = new Guid("B09A7990-05EA-4AF9-81EF-EDFAB16C4E31")
};
keywordQuery.RowLimit = 7;
keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("AccountName");
keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("SP-EmployeeID");
keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("JobTitle");  // add some extra select properties if you want
// logic to get specific user by custom property
// here, for example, am using RefinableString01 as managed property
keywordQuery.RefinementFilters.Add("RefinableString01:C001*");  
SearchExecutor e = new SearchExecutor();
// rest of the code
```

Comment: For Employee ID I would not use a refinable property as it is unique to each employee. You could create a new String property.

Comment: I am not able to get **SP-EmployeeID** in Crawled Property selection under Search Schema for People. SP-EmployeeID is custom property which I have created. Can you guys please tell me that how can I get it for the mapping with RefinableString?

Comment: is the full crawl of the people results source complete ? I guess with 100k users , it will take some time. Once the crawl is complete, it will appear under the people section, check the internal name of the property.

Comment: I have finished full crawl on weekend as it takes so much time to finish (You are correct on it). But still I am not able to get that property by it's internal name as well. Did I miss anything?

Comment: hmm, are there any errors in search crawl ? IF there are errors, i think that could be an issue with your crawled property not getting created. Other than that , i think you haven't missed anything. Once the property becomes available, you can just map it as you map any property

Comment: @hardik - just remembered, you need to set the user profile property as indexed. It will only be crawled after its set as indexed. After that, crawl again and check.